# Windows 7 - block websites for specific users using BAT to amend HOSTS file or Local GPO

Tags: windows-7, internet, batch-file, user-accounts, group-policy

I have a small home setup with one machine running Windows 7 SP2 still.

This computer as 2 user accounts. I need to block one user account from specific websites whilst allowing through the same websites for other user. Both might be logged in simultaneously at the same time or one might login only or one might login before the other.

I have tried running the following BAT files using Task Scheduler set to trigger upon login depending on the user. The block BAT file works but the allow BAT never works when I try logging in as the user with Allow BAT task scheduled upon login.

**Any ideas on the BAT files or the best way to set it up - or should I use some kind of Local Group Policy perhaps altogether instead?**

Allow BAT file:

> @echo off
>
> type c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts | findstr /v WEBSITE NAME HERE >
> c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Block BAT file:

> @echo off
>
> echo 0.0.0.0 WEBSITE NAME HERE >>
> c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Can you be more specific what "never works" means, how does the hosts file look after you run the bat file manually? What's the output of simply running `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts | findstr /v WEBSITE NAME HERE` in command line?

Comment: Why not have HOSTS_USER_A and HOSTS_USER_B for each of the users. On login, copy the relevant file above to HOSTS  (copy needs to be run as administrator).

Comment: @John - Windows only has a single hosts file.

Comment: You can also try to use a more detailed script solution to add and remove websites, something like this https://gist.github.com/markembling/173887

Comment: Windows only has a single hosts file.    ...........   Yes, of course so my thought is a file with a different name copied into HOSTS (the one file)

Answer (score 1):

> 

**Thank you for all your welcome and suggestions which helped me in the end to answer my own question.
In keeping with the spirit of these forums I will post my solution below so that others may benefit from all our efforts in years to come through stumbling upon this via search engines:**

---

To anyone else in the future looking for the answer - I figured it out.

The best way was to only apply the block and unblock to the user account that needed blocking in the first place. Let me explain:

I used Task Scheduler to run the block bat file I showed in my original question using the settings:

Security Options

- When running the task, use the following account: User Account 1
- Ticked the box for "Run only when user is logged on"
- Ticked the box for "Run with highest privileges"

Triggers Options

- On connection to user session
- Specific User (User Account 1)
- Connection from Local Computer

Actions

- Start a Program (my bat file)

Conditions

- Uncheck everything here

Settings

- Allow the task to run on demand ticked
- If the task is already running, then the following rule applies: Stop the existing instance

For the unblock I did the exact same as above APART from:

Trigger Options

- On disconnection from user session
- Specific User (User Account 1)
- Connection from Local Computer